# What will be $F'(x)?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $F:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ be defined by:

> > $F(x)=\int_{-x}^{x} ((1-e^{-xy})/y) dy$

What will be $F'(x)?$

Comment: Do you know Leibniz' integral rule (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement)?

Comment: Here, I would first do the substitution $u=y/x$ in the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Differentation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) states:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} F(x, y) \,dy = F\big(x,b(x)\big)\cdot b'(x) - F\big(x, a(x)\big)\cdot a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x, y) \,dy $$

Applying the rule:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{-x}^x \frac{1 - e^{-xy}}{y}\,dy = \frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x} - \left( -\frac{1-e^{x^2}}{-x} \right) + \int_{-x}^x e^{-xy}\,dy \\
= \frac{e^{x^2} - e^{-x^2}}{x} - \left[\frac{e^{-xy}}{x}\right]_{-x}^x = \frac{2\left(e^{x^2} - e^{-x^2}\right)}{x} $$

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake (not to say my stupidity !!). Cheers :-(

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the [fundamental theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) of calculus after rewriting
$$
\int_{-x}^x\ldots=\int_{-\infty}^x\ldots-\int_{-\infty}^{-x}\ldots.
$$

Comment: Is the answer $(e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2})/x$?

Comment: No quite. I think you've lost a minus sign along the way.